# How to modify this script so I can insert data without uploading an image?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks for reading my question.
I found a google apps script on the internet that uploads an image to google drive, and it worked for me. Then I made some modifications in it - I added some columns with `appendRow()` method. But this script doesn't work if there is no image uploaded.

I'm new and still learning about google apps script. Please, teach me how to modify this script, so even without uploading an image the script still will be able to insert data.

This is the script I've modified:

```
function doGet(e) {return message("Error: no parameters in doGet")}

function doPost(e) {
 if (!e.parameters.filename ||!e.parameters.file ||!e.parameters.imageformat) {return message("Error: Bad parameters in doPost");} else {
var imgf = e.parameters.imageformat[0].toUpperCase();
var mime =
    (imgf == 'BMP')  ? MimeType.BMP
  : (imgf == 'GIF')  ? MimeType.GIF
  : (imgf == 'JPEG') ? MimeType.JPEG
  : (imgf == 'JPG')  ? MimeType.JPEG
  : (imgf == 'PNG')  ? MimeType.PNG
  : (imgf == 'SVG')  ? MimeType.SVG
  : false;
if (mime) {
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.file, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, mime, e.parameters.filename);

  //get the image file ID like this:
  var content =  DriveApp.getFolderById('folderID').createFile(blob);
  var imageID = content.getId();
  var imageName = content.getName();
  var imageshowlink = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + imageID;
  var pertanyaan = e.parameter.pertanyaan1;
  var jwbA = e.parameter.jawabA;
  var jwbB = e.parameter.jawabB;
  var jwbC = e.parameter.jawabC;
  var jwbD = e.parameter.jawabD;
  var kunci = e.parameter.kuncijwb;

  //append the ID to your spreadsheet like this:
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SS ID');
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sh.appendRow([imageID, imageName, imageshowlink, pertanyaan, jwbA, jwbB, jwbC, jwbD, kunci]);
  return message("Success");
  } else {return message("Error: Bad image format");}
}
}

function message(msg) {
return  
ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({Result: msg })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);}
```

Comment: Ezra, am I correct in assuming that the script execution returns with an "Error: Ba parameters in doPost" if there is no image to be uploaded via the `POST` request?

Comment: Yes...where should i modify to fix it?

Comment: Then, first of all, get rid of the first line in `doPost()` function - it literally states that if `event object` constructed in response to `POST` either: 1). Does not have a filename set (`filename`); 2). Does not contain a file (`file` property); 3). Does not have a format set (`imageformat` property) -> stop execution and return with an error message. The only thing I am not sure of - can you please explain what exactly do you want it to do if there is no image to upload (e.g. what type of data)?

Comment: Thanks Oleg, i just want insert data with uploading image once in one click, also i get the link image added in the column...so i try to mix image upload script and insert data to spreadsheet with that appendRow. Do you have other suggestion? i'm very new with google app script

Comment: I'd like to see the client side code.

Comment: i'm using app inventor/kodular  to insert data and upload image